# python speech_recognition runs my pc into problem

Tags: python, windows, crash, speech-to-text

Hi guys I've been trying to implement speech_recognition module in python but my pc runs into problem.It does not show any errors but still it abruptly crashes my entire pc and it has to reboot itself every time i run the code.I tried it on jupyter notebook and it works fine,but it doesn't work if I execute it from command prompt.

The code i tried to implement is :

```
import speech_recognition as sr


r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    try:
        print("speak..")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(text)
    except:
        print("something went wrong")
```

Here's the error that I have been getting:
[image: error]

Comment: This doesn't look like it would [BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death) your machine...

Comment: @WaiHaLee the error code indicated is 'PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA' which suggests a memory access violation.  It's possible that `speech_recognition` under the hood is doing something Windows doesn't like, which explains why it could crash with *that* specific error.  It could also indicate there's some type of driver failure in the audio drivers that's trying to access invalid system memory and causing the Blue Screen, but it's possible that it could just be the `speech_recognition` module just doing a stupid.